JBoss 7.4.12 JMS connectivity with Spring JMS 6.1.5
When I create a producer using Java Spring in my logs I am getting:
Failed to Convert property value of type org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory to required type jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory for property targetConnectionFactory

I am using jboss-client jar in my classpath. What might be the issue? I am expecting to send the message via JBoss JMS connection.

JBoss 7.4 is Jakarta EE8 whilst Spring 6.x is JakartaEE 9+. So you either need to downgrade to Spring 5.3 or use a newer JBoss version.

Ok.I think you are right.I tried with javax which was present in spring jms 5 version.Exception gone.Is jboss- client 8 version available with jakarta support?
